# Using convert::Into with enum to unwrap and convert value

Tags: rust, hyper

I'm starting to get comfortable with Rust, but there are still some things that are really tripping me up with lifetimes. In this particular case, what I want to do is have an enum which may have different types wrapped as a generic parameter class to create strongly typed query parameters in a URL, though the specific use case is irrelevant, and return a conversion of that wrapped value into an &str. Here's an example of what I want to do:

```rust
enum Param<'a> {
   MyBool(bool),
   MyLong(i64),
   MyStr(&'a str),
}

impl<'a> Param<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> (&'static str, &'a str) {
        match self {
            Param::MyBool(b) => ("my_bool", &b.to_string()), // clearly wrong
            Param::MyLong(i) => ("my_long", &i.to_string()), // clearly wrong
            Param::Value(s) => ("my_str", s),
        }
    }
}
```

What I ended up doing is this to deal with the obvious lifetime issue (and yes, it's obvious to me why the lifetime isn't long enough for the into() function):

```rust
enum Param<'a> {
   MyBool(&'a str), // no more static typing :(
   MyLong(&'a str), // no more static typing :(
   MyStr(&'a str),
}

impl<'a> Param<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> (&'static str, &'a str) {
        match self {
            Param::MyBool(b) => ("my_bool", b),
            Param::MyLong(i) => ("my_long", i),
            Param::Value(s) => ("my_str", s),
        }
    }
}
```

This seems like an ugly workaround in a case where what I really want to do is guarantee the static typing of certain params, b/c now it's the constructor of the enum that's responsible for the proper type conversion. Curious if there is a way to do this... and yes, at some point I need &str as that is a parameter elsewhere, specifically:

```rust
let body = url::form_urlencoded::serialize(
               vec![Param::MyBool(&true.to_string()).
                       into()].
                   into_iter());
```

I went through a whole bunch of things like trying to return String instead of `&str` from `into()`, but that only caused conversion issues down the line with a `map()` of `String` -> `&str`. Having the tuple correct from the start is the easiest thing, rather than fighting the compiler at every turn after that.

-- update--

Ok, so I went back to a `(String,String)` tuple in the `into()` function for the enum. It turns out that there is an "owned" version of the `url::form_urlencoded::serialize()` function which this is compatible with.

```
pub fn serialize_owned(pairs: &[(String, String)]) -> String
```

But, now I'm also trying to use the same pattern for the query string in the `hyper::URL`, specifically:

```
fn set_query_from_pairs<'a, I>(&mut self, pairs: I) 
    where I: Iterator<Item=(&'a str, &'a str)>
```

and then I try to use `map()` on the iterator that I have from the (String,String) tuple:

```
params: Iterator<Item=(String, String)>

url.set_query_from_pairs(params.map(|x: (String, String)| -> 
    (&str, &str) { let (ref k, ref v) = x; (k, v) } ));
```

But this gets error: `x.0` does not live long enough. Ref seems correct in this case, right? If I don't use ref, then it's k/v that don't live long enough. Is there something 'simple' that I'm missing in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really clear why you can't do this:

```rust
enum Param<'a> {
   MyBool(bool),
   MyLong(i64),
   MyStr(&'a str),
}

impl<'a> Param<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> (&'static str, String) {
        match self {
            Param::MyBool(b) => ("my_bool", b.to_string()),
            Param::MyLong(i) => ("my_long", i.to_string()),
            Param::MyStr(s) => ("my_str", s.into()),
        }
    }
}
```

(`into()` for `&str -> String` conversion is slightly more efficient than `to_string()`)

You can always get a `&str` from `String`, e.g. with deref coercion or explicit slicing.

Comment: There's also `std::borrow::Cow<str>`.

Comment: So the issue is that later I need to convert to &str for the vector being passed into the serialize function. if I use String in the Param, then I need to unwrap that for the vec! being passed into serialize, which requires a map() method on the Iterator at that point. Then the function on that map needs to do a move from the String to &str: `fn map_str_string<'a>(value: (&'static str, String)) -> (&'static str, &'a str) {
     let (k,v) = value;
     return (k,&v);
 }`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered, but re-ask the interator conversation question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI, for the question around iterator (String,String) to (&str, &str) conversion  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818290/how-to-convert-an-iterator-on-a-tuple-of-string-string-to-an-iterator-of-st/29818920#29818920