# How to convert an Iterator on a tuple of (String, String) to an Iterator of (&str, &str)?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having trouble converting from an Iterator of `(String, String)` to an Iterator of `(&str, &str)`. I'm using an external library, so can't change the signature of that, and not sure that I need to. Basically I have this function def:

```rust
use hyper;

fn build_url<'a, I>(host: &'a str, port: u16, path: &'a str, params: I) -> 
   hyper::Url where I: Iterator<Item=(String, String)> {

       let mut url = hyper::Url::parse(&format!("http://{h}:{p}/{pt}",
                                            h = self.etcd_host,
                                            p = self.etcd_port,
                                            pt = path));
       if let Err(e) = url {
           panic!("error parsing url: {}", e);
       }

       let mut url = url.unwrap();

       // fn set_query_from_pairs<'a, I>(&mut self, pairs: I)
       //  where I: Iterator<Item=(&'a str, &'a str)>
       url.set_query_from_pairs(
            params.map(|x: (String, String)| -> 
                       (&str, &str) { let (ref k, ref v) = x; (k, v) } ));

}
```

But I'm getting the dreaded: `error: 'x.0' does not live long enough`

I think the `ref` keyword in the let should have been the right thing here, i.e. keep the ownership with the Iterator, and just do a borrow. I get a similar issue if I get rid of `ref` in the let changing the let to this:

```
let (k, v) = x; (&k, &v)
```

Then `k` and `v` don't live long enough. Does anyone have a recommendation for fixing this?

Comment: what you need is a streaming iterator. Those aren't possible yet. But there might be an alternative. where are you getting the `params` iterator from? is it a map or a vector? If so, you can create a non-owning iterator from that and then map it to a `(&str, &str)` iterator

Comment: yes, it's actually from a vec![] creation, so I can change that param type...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have an iterator that (safely) yields references to any internal or owned state; the `Iterator` trait is just not designed to allow it.  These sorts of constructs are usually known as "streaming iterators", and they're something of a hole in the language/stdlib at the moment.

Consider what happens to a `(String, String)` value as it flows through your `map` call.  Each tuple is returned from `I::next`, which causes ownership to pass into the closure you gave to `map`.  Thus, when you use `ref` in the closure, you're taking a reference to variables *which are local to the closure*.  You now construct a new tuple, return it and... because the closure owns the `String`s (they're being stored in `k` and `v`), they are destroyed, thus invalidating the references you tried to return.

The problem is that there is *no way* to avoid taking ownership of the `(String, String)` items.

Now, that having been said, you *can* cheat here.  All you need to do is guarantee that the `(String, String)` values continue to exist beyond each individual step in the iterator.  Thus:

```
let params: Vec<_> = params.collect();
url.set_query_from_pairs(params.iter().map(|&(ref x, ref y)| (&x[..], &y[..])))
```

This works because `Vec::iter` gives us `Iterator<Item=&(String, String)>`, from which we can borrow *without* taking ownership (which is retained by `params`).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the &x[..] is that documented somewhere? I don't recall it in the book or other resources I've read.

Comment: this worked for me: `url.set_query_from_pairs(params.iter().map(|&(ref k,ref v)| -> (&'a str, &'a str) { (k,v) }));`

Comment: to be clear, I switched my method signature to use &'a Vec and then made the &str's in the mapping bind to that lifetime.

Comment: @bluejekyll, `&x[..]` is what we call a slicing syntax. `x[..]` is an indexing operation which takes a `FullRange` object (`..`) - for a `String` it means returning a `str` which correspond to the entire string. Then `&` is used to obtain an `&str`. You can also write e.g. `&x[1..]` to slice a string from the second byte to the end. This syntax is described [here](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/arrays-vectors-and-slices.html).

Comment: Your approach worked due to deref coercion - `k` and `v` are `&String`s, and `&String` can be automatically converted to `&str` in certain contexts where the target type (`&str` in this case) is known.

Comment: @bluejekyll it was added to http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/primitive-types.html#slices within the last week or so

Answer (score 4):

Since your `params` argument is created from a `Vec<(String, String)>` you can change your where clause to `where I: Iterator<Item=(&str, &str)>` and get the iterator by calling

```
your_vector.iter().map(|(a, b)|, (&a[..], &b[..])))
```

A simplified example:

```rust
fn test<'a, I>(it: I)
    where I: Iterator<Item=&'a str>
{
    for s in it {
        dump(s);
    }
}

fn dump(s: &str) {
    println!("{}", s);
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!["a".to_string(), "42".to_string()];
    test(v.iter().map(|s| &s[..]));
}
```