# How do I convert an iterator to an iterator of references in Rust?

Tags: rust

As the title says, how would one go about converting an `Iterator<Item = T>` to `Iterator<Item = &'a T>` (which is to be passed to a function) **without** collecting the contents of the iterator?

Basically, I want to accomplish the following:

```rust
fn foo<'a, T>(data: impl Iterator<Item = &'a T>){
    // ..
}

let data: Vec<T> = ...;
let iter = data.iter().map(|t| {
    let mut nt = t.clone();
    // mutate nt...
    return nt;
});

foo(iter); // Error: expected &T, iter returns T
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. For something to be borrowed it must be owned by something, so you can't create a iterator of references without having the items themselves exist outside the iterator. You could create a iterator of `Box<T>` though which is basically the same things.

Comment: What is the goal here? If the iterator owns the items, then they'll go away if you discard that iterator in favor of a new, non-owning iterator. Is the goal to iterate it by reference while *keeping* the original iterator for later use?

Comment: @infixint943: Okay, so the goal is really just laziness (in a programmatic sense)/memory-efficiency? You want to have `foo` consume mutated elements from `Vec`, without eagerly creating the mutated elements (and thereby consuming the memory for `n` mutated elements up front), but your function doesn't want to consume the elements (thus receiving the reference-based iterator)?

Comment: @infixint943: I think the answer to your question is basically the same as the one to [How to convert an Iterator on a tuple of (String, String) to an Iterator of (&str, &str)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29818290/364696) (to the point where it's probably a valid duplicate). Iterators can't yield references to internally owned state, because the ownership lapses the moment it yields. The dupe is a little more specific, but it's ultimately the same problem; the moment you `clone`, you've got your own internal state, and it's not going to survive past the return.

Comment: That post answers my question (a google search yielded no useful results). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of to get references to items without an owner is to [leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) them. It's most likely not what you want but here it is anyways:

```rust
fn leak_it<T>(i: impl Iterator<Item = T>) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'static T> {
    i.map(|x| &*Box::leak(Box::new(x)))
}
```

To avoid leaking the memory for good either you have to store the references (in which case you should just collect the items in the first place) or the function you're calling has to return them so you can turn them back into a box with [`Box::from_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.from_raw) and properly free the memory.